# How to get the name of the month in local language in Drupal?

Tags: datetime, i18n-l10n

I want to display in a tpl.php file:

> 30 maart 2015, 11: 34

Currently i'm using below code

```
    <?php print  date("j-F-Y H:i") ?>
```

1) How to get the name of the month in dutch instead of english?

2) How to add the comma easily ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the PHP `date` function, use the Drupal API: `format_date`. To add the comma, make it part of the pattern. To match your example `30 maart 2015, 11: 34`, the pattern is `j F Y, H: i`:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2015-03-30 11:34');
print format_date($timestamp, 'custom', 'j F Y, H: i', NULL, 'nl');
```

For this to work, you need to have the core **locale** module enabled and Dutch translations on your site should be up to date (check that the names of months are translated inthe translation UI).  The module [**Localization Update**](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) will help you with updating translations if you need to.

You can skip the last argument (`'nl'`) if the default language of your site is dutch.